# Dynamically matching bodyFileName to default file when no match

Tags: wiremock

I am running this using the json request mappings and am running the base Docker image with my repo mounted as a volume. I don't want to do any coding for this because then I'd have to also create the docker file and manage the image and change some scripting. The matcher will take data from the request which should map to a file in the __files directory. If the there is no file then the server returns 500. When not found I'd like to either return the generic not found response or more preferably a default response I create.

```
{
  "response": {
    "bodyFileName": "{{complicated parsing}}-{{complicated parsing}}.json",
  }
```

One idea I was thinking is adding a request matcher like this:

```
  "request": {
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {first complicated parse is in the possible file names},
      {second complicated parse is in the possible file names}
    ]
  }
```

So in this case we could have files a-b.json, a-c.json b-c.json and b-d.json, If I add a request matcher to match on my parsing logic for each value then it still will fail because I can make a request that will map to a-d.json since the first pattern will match a or b and the second will match b, c or d. The other draw back is I'd have to track all possible values.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/2470